# firebase admin in node js not working in digital ocean

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, digital-ocean, firebase-admin

Firebase admin sdk doesn't work when it's uploaded to digital ocean, but when it's run on a local computer it runs fine. help me to solve this problem

this is my code

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./firebase-adminsdk.json'); 
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});
```

this code does not work and makes the application not run due to an error. when code is removed the application returns to running properly.

please help me to setting in digital ocean

Comment: What error specifically? "Doesn't work" is not a helpful symptom, please add more details.

Comment: error in web access with error 500

Comment: Please edit the question with the text of the full stack trace. 500 could be a number of things.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: no errors detected, but when I deleted the above code the service returned to normal